# Download video with blob url

Tags: python, instagram

I am working on a Python project to scrap videos from Instagram using Selenium and request.
I am following the following link but it seems Instagram changed its settings:
`https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3DCtaJvf6VA&list=PLEsfXFp6DpzQjDBvhNy5YbaBx9j-ZsUe6&index=17&ab_channel=CodingEntrepreneurs`

However, after I get a link of Instagram video, it's like this:

```
blob:https://www.instagram.com/4ddaf674-312a-4366-ad12-136bda7b6c8e
```

Hence, I cannot download the video. And I have looked at similar posts and they can find m3u8 or .ts in the Inspection. However, I cannot find any of them. Could anyone help?

Comment: use without login